# How to get a result from a restricted list of data?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I want the list to be conditioned only by "controle." I have the following method in my DAOImpl:

```
 public List getControle_versao(int controle){

     return (List) session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Receita order by titulo").list();
}
```

And my Controller, I have this:

```
 @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/listarReceita/{controle}/versoes")
public String listVersions(@PathVariable("controle") int controle, Map<String, Object> map) {

    map.put("versoesList", receitaService.getControle_versao(controle));  

    return "listVersions";
}
```

But instead of showing only the data defined by "controle" has returned all data. What am I doing wrong?

Help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using your `controle` parameter. The query has no `where` clause, thus is returning all the data instead of filtering. Your query should probably look more like:

```
public List getControle_versao(int controle) {

    return (List) session.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
        "FROM Receita WHERE controle = " + controle + " ORDER BY titulo").list();

}
```